# Turning on React Native debugger in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I'm dealing with like 7 files so it would be crazy to post them all.  I'm getting a very vague error in my `iOS` simulator that says:

```
A valid ReactComponent must be returned. 
You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I'm not getting any error in the IDE, only when I run the simulator is when I see the error above.  I'm using the `WebStorm` IDE.  I would like to use some sort of debugger to point me exactly where this error is, how would I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/ for some tips on debugging React native apps in webstorm

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with WebStorm, you didn't return something in some of your component. You can enable debugging in iOS simulator by using shake gesture or pressing Cmd+R, you can get the logs in chrome console or use [this](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) application. To point you to the exact issue, it would be helpful if you could share a gist or link to some repo with your code.